# How can I further tune the following algorithm (Java) to make it go even faster?

Tags: java, performance, opencv

## Introduction

I have currently implemented the algorithm from this [Paper (Efficiently selecting spatially distributed keypoints for visual tracking)](http://lucafoschini.com/papers/Efficiently_ICIP11.pdf) in java.
I have not done the following recommendation from the paper (page 3 in the end of section 5):

> The relatively expensive cell cover operation can be substantially
>   sped up by using a single bit to store the state of each cell
>   of Gr. This enables using bitwise OR operations to “cover” contiguous
>   patches at once with precomputed bitmasks that implement the
>   cover to be applied at a given bit-offset position.

### Testing, benchmarking and profiling

- The testing of the algorithm tests by creating 12 000 random points, and executing the algorithm once with an initial radius. [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) test is attached.
- I profile continuously with [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) for object memory throughput (not many objects actually are created), CPU (its a CPU bottleneck), GC (nothing much happen here), and the CPU bottleneck is currently inside the bresenhamFilledCircle method (that is where all the action happens). 
  of the 12.000 points, about 1.500 of them is returned from the main algorithm, thus the bresenhamFilledCircle is executed approximately 1.500 * 6.700 = about 10 million times pr. second. That is about 0.1 microseconds (100 nanoseconds) pr invocation. Quite fast, but there should be room to make it go even faster....

### What I have done so far

- Started with a basic brute force algorithm: two nested loops for rows and cols, and a standard [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to figure out if I am inside a circle or not, to "paint" the circle to a boolean[][].
   `throughput ~3 500 ops/sec`.
- Switched to using System.arrayCopy for filling instead of bruteforcing.
  `throughput ~5 600 ops/sec`.
- Optimized array initialization (used caching).
   `throughput ~6 000 ops/sec`.
- Added margins on the rows and the cols to avoid bounds-checking during algorithm.
   `throughput ~6 500 ops/sec`.
- Switched over to [Bresenham's circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) (slightly modified to fill circle) to avoid "complex" Pythagorean checks.
   `throughput ~6 500 ops/sec`. :(
- Switched from 2D array to 1D array..
   `throughput ~6 700 ops/sec`.

Now I am out of ideas, except converting the boolean[] to a byte[] and using bitmasks for setting/getting as suggested if I have understood the suggestion from the paper correctly.

Anyone up for a challenge?

Below is the JMH test:

```
public class KeyPointFilterBenchmark {
    private static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 10;

    @Benchmark
    public List<OpenCVKeyPoint> benchmarkFilterByRadius(KeyPointFilterState state) {
        return state.filter.filterByRadius(DEFAULT_RADIUS, state.list);
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class KeyPointFilterState {
        private static final int NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 12_000;
        private static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 640;
        private static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 480;
        private static final int RESPONSE_RANGE = 255;
        private List<OpenCVKeyPoint> list;
        private KeyPointFilter filter;

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void doSetup() {
            this.list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_POINTS; i++) {
                double x = Math.random() * IMAGE_WIDTH;
                double y = Math.random() * IMAGE_HEIGHT;
                float response = (float) (Math.random() * RESPONSE_RANGE);
                list.add(new OpenCVKeyPoint(x, y, response));
            }
            this.filter = new KeyPointFilter(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

The current implementation:

```
public class KeyPointFilter {
    private boolean[] matrix;
    private final int rowCount;
    private final int colCount;
    private int matrixColCount;
    private int matrixRowCount;
    private boolean[] ones;
    private int radiusInitialized;

    public KeyPointFilter(int colCount, int rowCount) {
        this.colCount = colCount;
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }

    void init(int radius) {
        if (radiusInitialized == radius) {
            // Already initialized, just reset.
            this.matrix = new boolean[matrixRowCount * matrixColCount];
            return;
        }
        this.matrixRowCount = rowCount + radius * 2;
        this.matrixColCount = colCount + radius * 2;
        this.matrix = new boolean[matrixRowCount * matrixColCount];
        // Initialize a one array, to use in the coverAround arraycopy optimization.
        this.ones = new boolean[matrixColCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < ones.length; i++) {
            ones[i] = true;
        }
        radiusInitialized = radius;
    }

    public List<OpenCVKeyPoint> filterByRadius(int radius, List<OpenCVKeyPoint> input) {
        init(radius);
        List<OpenCVKeyPoint> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        // Eliminating by covering
        for (OpenCVKeyPoint point : input) {
            int col = (int) point.getXPos();
            int row = (int) point.getYPos();
            if (!isSet(col, row)) {
                bresenhamFilledCircle(col, row, radius);
                filtered.add(point);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    void bresenhamFilledCircle(int col, int row, int radius) {
        // CHECKSTYLE IGNORE MagicNumber FOR NEXT 1 LINES.
        int d = (5 - radius * 4) / 4;
        int x = 0;
        int y = radius;
        int rowOffset = radius + row;
        int colOffset = radius + col;
        do {
            //Since we are filling a circle, we fill using System.arraycopy, from left to right.
            int yStart = colOffset - y;
            int yLength = 2 * y;
            // Row a bottom
            System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(rowOffset - x, yStart), yLength);
            if (x != 0) {
                int xStart = colOffset - x;
                int xLength = 2 * x;
                // Row a top
                System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(rowOffset + x, yStart), yLength);
                // Row b bottom
                System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(rowOffset - y, xStart), xLength);
                // Row b top
                System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(rowOffset + y, xStart), xLength);
            }
            if (d < 0) {
                d += 2 * x + 1;
            } else {
                d += 2 * (x - y) + 1;
                y--;
            }
            x++;
        } while (x <= y);
    }

    private int getIndex(int row, int col) {
        return row * matrixColCount + col;
    }

    private void debugArray() {
        StringBuilder actualResult = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < getColCount(); col++) {
                actualResult.append(isSet(col, row) ? '1' : '0');
            }
            actualResult.append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println(actualResult);
    }

    public boolean isSet(int col, int row) {
        return matrix[getIndex(row + radiusInitialized, col + radiusInitialized)];
    }

    int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }

    int getColCount() {
        return colCount;
    }
}
```

Plus the keypoint class to use:

```
public class OpenCVKeyPoint {
    private final double xPos;
    private final double yPos;
    private final float response;

    public OpenCVKeyPoint(double xPos, double yPos, float response) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.response = response;
    }

    public float getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public double getXPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public double getYPos() {
        return yPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Profile it, work out where the bottleneck it. Work from there. Without doing that we are just shooting in the dark. But generally speaking, `new` in highly performance sensitive code is a smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out a nice optimization.
The generic Bresenham algorithm will cause several paints at the same position near the top and the bottom of the circle, but by using a custom strategy,
we can have a specific painting for e.g. 10 radius, that does no more then necessary, and have almost no calculations at all.
A custom strategy for circles of radius 10 would be something like this:

```
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row, col + 7), 6);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 1, col + 4), 12);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 2, col + 3), 14);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 3, col + 2), 16);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 4, col + 1), 18);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 5, col + 1), 18);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 6, col + 1), 18);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 7, col), 20);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 8, col), 20);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 9, col), 20);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 10, col), 20);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 11, col), 20);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 12, col), 20);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 13, col), 20);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 14, col + 1), 18);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 15, col + 1), 18);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 16, col + 1), 18);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 17, col + 2), 16);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 18, col + 3), 14);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 19, col + 4), 12);
System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, getIndex(row + 20, col + 7), 6);
```

Did a new benchmark, and got an increase in throughput, now up to ~8 200 ops/sec.

Could probably get even higher if I introduce threads, and execute the list in parallell, but this throughput is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache more calculations and inline functions as much as possible.

Try replacing `filterByRadius` with this and see if there's any improvement:

```
public List<OpenCVKeyPoint> filterByRadius(final int radius, List<OpenCVKeyPoint> input) {
    init(radius);

    // Possibly give a hint to the arraylist on how much space to allocate from the start.
    List<OpenCVKeyPoint> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

    // calculate once
    final int d_init = (5 - radius * 4) / 4;

    // Eliminating by covering
    for (OpenCVKeyPoint point : input) {

        // FIXME do the points need to be doubles, only to be cast to int?
        int col = (int) point.getXPos();
        int row = (int) point.getYPos();

        if (!isSet(col, row)) {
            final int rowOffset = (radius + row) * matrixColCount;
            final int colOffset = radius + col;

            int d = d_init;
            int x = 0;
            int y = radius;
            do {
                final int yStart = colOffset - y;
                final int yLength = 2 * y;

                final int xByMatrixColCount = x * matrixColCount;
                final int rowOffsetPlusYStart = rowOffset + yStart;

                // Since we are filling a circle, we fill using System.arraycopy, from left to right.

                // Row a bottom
                System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, (rowOffsetPlusYStart - xByMatrixColCount),
                        yLength);
                if (x != 0) {
                    // Row a top
                    System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, (rowOffsetPlusYStart + xByMatrixColCount),
                            yLength);

                    // -----
                    final int xLength = 2 * x;
                    final int yByMatrixColCount = y * matrixColCount;
                    final int rowOffsetPlusXStart = rowOffset + colOffset - x;

                    // Row b bottom
                    System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, (rowOffsetPlusXStart - yByMatrixColCount),
                            xLength);

                    // Row b top
                    System.arraycopy(ones, 0, matrix, (rowOffsetPlusXStart + yByMatrixColCount),
                            xLength);
                }
                if (d < 0) {
                    d += 2 * x + 1;
                } else {
                    d += 2 * (x - y) + 1;
                    y--;
                }
                x++;
            } while (x <= y);

            filtered.add(point);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

This probably wont be too significant of an improvement, but you asked for faster and I think this will be ever-so-slightly faster, though I have no measurements to back me up. If you benchmark this then I'd love to know the results!

Comment: I have tried the code, and while I also thought that the caching of calculations would slightly improve the performance, (The inlining not, in my experience, hotspot like lot's of small methods that it can inline itself), but alas, the throughput was just about the same, 6.700 ops/sec.

Comment: You're right, I sometimes forget how good Hotspot is. Have you tried initializing your `ArrayList` size so that it doesn't have to grow as much, maybe that will have a measurable effect.

Comment: I tried initializing ArrayList to 2000, and effect was not noticeable, as the circlePainting far outweights the cost of a simple array growth. 
I am currently investigating another direction:
Encapsulating the matrix access, (will probably make it slower),
removing the extra margins and throw back the bounds checking in the algorithm. (maybe faster or slower). Will make the code simpler at least, and easier to attempt using byte[] and bit shifting. (potential 8x performance increase)

Comment: Byte[] and bitshifting provet to be a bit slower. I used lookup arrays for the bitshifting and the divisions, but the end result was slower. My guess is that system.arraycopy already do SIMD instructions, so my attempt to do “manual SIMD” with the added complexity of keeping track of the bits and bytes probably resulted in more machine instructions.

Comment: Yea, bitmasks are good for saving 7 bits of memory per flag but it adds cpu work to set/get flag (treated like an array of bits in an array) so I guess it's not worth it unless you're hitting memory thresholds such as paging.